# My app looks good at 2x on iPad - how can I remove the 2x button?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have a game which is for iPhone, made with Cocos2d. It's currently on the app store, and when I play it on my iPad at 2x, everything is really good quality and it wouldn't need any modifications for an iPad version.

So, my question is: how can I make the app available for iPad (as an actual iPad app) if it is currently for iPhone?

Selecting Universal in Xcode makes everything be at the bottom of the screen, so I wanna know how to make everything look just like the iPhone version, but for iPad.

Please help me! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost on the right track.

- First thing you have to do is make your project universal.
- This will give you two storyboards.
- if any stuff you incorporated for your iPhone storyboard you have to make the same changed to iPad storyboard
- Now comes the tricky part, you have to adjust all your graphics, layout, codes for bigger screen resolution i.e. for 1024 x 768. If you had hard coded views and graphics at a certain position of iPhones screen then you need to make sure you adjust them properly for bigger iPad screen.
- You will have to add something like below in your code to take into account iPhone and iPad
- Or you can just make a new version of your game just for iPad. (Double the revenue :-)

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
            {

```
            if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
            {
                CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
                if(result.height == 480)
                {
                    // iPhone Classic - regular
                }
                if(result.height == 568)
                {
                    // iPhone 5

                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //its iPad
        }
```